# My screen settings aren't saving on reboot

Tags: nvidia

I'm trying to use Elementary OS with NVIDIA drivers, and I have a two monitor layout. However, I disabled my secondary monitor to allow high refresh rates to work properly on my primary monitor. But whenever I restart Elementary, the settings don't save. I don't want to unplug the second monitor since I am dual booting Windows with it.

Anyone have any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier option to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to cycle display modes, this way with a few pressings on the <kbd>p</kbd> key while you hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key you will go through all setups until you have the one with the diabled secondary monitor. I believe your settings are saved into `~/.config/monitors.xml` file, but for some reason after restart the OS searches for a dual monitor setup and starts with it first. What I did before for a simular problem was to edit this file and remove all the settings excluding the monitor setup I want to use, but it was not permanent for a long time.

**note**: `~` above means your home folder.